# Failed to set module rewrite to enabled: Module rewrite already enabled

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm getting the following error when attempting to enable an already enabled Apache2 Module on `Ubuntu 16.04`:

```
Failed to set module rewrite to enabled: Module rewrite already enabled
```

My task

```
- name: Enable mod_rewrite
  apache2_module:
    state: present
    name: rewrite
    force: true
    ignore_configcheck: true
```

The error in Ansible

```
TASK [apache : Enable mod_rewrite] ****************************************************************************
fatal: [vps]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set module rewrite to enabled: Module rewrite already enabled\n", "rc": 0, "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Module rewrite already enabled\n", "stdout_lines": ["Module rewrite already enabled"]}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/me/ansible_ubuntu/ansible/playbook.retry
```

I'm on Ansible `2.4.0`.

I've tried to use the `force` parameter, then `ignore_configcheck`, all giving the same results.

Client Python: `2.7.6`
Server Python: `2.7.12`

**Update #1**

Shouldn't it just continue stating that it's installed rather than stop?

**Update #2**

Output of `a2dismod`

```
me@server:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ a2dismod
Your choices are: access_compat alias auth_basic authn_core authn_file authz_core authz_host authz_user autoindex deflate dir env fastcgi filter headers mime mpm_event negotiation proxy proxy_fcgi rewrite setenvif status
Which module(s) do you want to disable (wildcards ok)?
```

**Update #3**

I changed the task per one of the comments to reflect the whole name of the module:

```
- name: Enable mod_rewrite
  apache2_module:
    state: present
    name: mod_rewrite
    force: true
    ignore_configcheck: true
```

Got a different error:

```
TASK [apache : Enable mod_rewrite] ****************************************************************************
fatal: [vps]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set module mod_rewrite to enabled: ", "rc": 1, "stderr": "ERROR: Module mod_rewrite does not exist!\n", "stderr_lines": ["ERROR: Module mod_rewrite does not exist!"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/me/ansible_ubuntu/ansible/playbook.retry
```

Update #4

Solution

In `task.yml`:

```
- name: Enable mod_rewrite
  apache2_module:
    state: present
    name: rewrite
    force: true
    ignore_configcheck: true
```

In `ansible/modules/web_infrastructure/apache2_modules.py`

```
# a2enmod name replacement to apache2ctl -M names
text_workarounds = [
    ('shib2', 'mod_shib'),
    ('evasive', 'evasive20_module'),
    ('rewrite', 'rewrite_module'),
    ('headers', 'headers_module'),
]
```

Comment: Is `a2dismod` installed on the target host/s?

Comment: I believe it is, see update #2

Comment: This looks crazy, but Ansible handles some situations resulting in this error with hardcoded module names. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/web_infrastructure/apache2_module.py#L153 Can you try with `name: mod_rewrite` instead? And check what is the name of the module in `apache2ctl -M` results.

Comment: @techraf, tried your suggestion and got a different error.

Comment: On a side: do you really think there are hundreds of users checking this question every now and then, so that you need to mark every change with "update"? It has 31 views (count me as 4 on different devices).

Comment: I asked you what's the result of `apache2ctl -M`, didn't I? It lists the module as `rewrite_module` so you are running into exactly the same problem as `evasive` and `shib2` -- you can fix the code yourself or submit an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @techraf posting my updates to keep track of what I have done, mostly for me TBH :) Indeed, the result is rewrite_module that is being output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into a [well-known problem](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22635) with Apache 2 on Ubuntu.

Some packages have different names in the output of `apache2ctl -M` and this is the case for `rewrite` too. The command lists it as `rewrite_module` which confuses Ansible.

Ansible fixes this by providing a [workaround with hard-coded pair of names](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/6b6a145027b499e6be43133c725908d04ef5aaf8/lib/ansible/modules/web_infrastructure/apache2_module.py#L153). You can modify your module directly by adding `('rewrite', 'rewrite_module')`:

```
text_workarounds = [
    ('shib2', 'mod_shib'),
    ('evasive', 'evasive20_module'),
    ('rewrite', 'rewrite_module'),
]
```

Comment: So, directly in Ansible's code? Or is there a way to provide this in my playbook and thus not affecting Ansible's code? Furthermore, any updates to Ansible will require me to redo this work ?

Comment: Works. Edited apache2_module.py. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From ansible 2.5 you could use [identifier](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/apache2_module_module.html#parameter-identifier) for this:

> Identifier of the module as listed by apache2ctl -M. This is optional
> and usually determined automatically by the common convention of
> appending _module to name as well as custom exception for popular
> modules.